# Bash shell script program that prompts for and reads two integers from the user.

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, centos, arithmetic

Okay, so I been trying to figure this problem for a while and I'm coming up with errors left and right. This is my first time trying to learn the basics. So any advice would be helpful!

Problem: I'm trying to write a Bash shell script program that prompts for and reads two integers from the user.  The second argument is assumed to be greater than the first.  The output of the program is a counting of numbers beginning at the first number and ending with the second number.

In other words the output would look like this:

```
    Please enter the first number:
    3
    Please enter the second number, larger than the first:
    6

    3
    4
    5
    6
```

Okay, so this is what I have so far~

```
    read -p "Please Enter the first number : " n1
     echo "$n1"
   read -p "Please Enter the second number, larger than the first : " n2
     echo "$n2"
   FIRSTV=0
   SECONDV=1
   if [ 1 -gt 0]
   then
   count=$((FIRSTV-SECONDV))
   echo $COUNT
   fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `seq`, you could do this:

```
read -p "Please Enter the first number : " n1
echo "$n1"
read -p "Please Enter the second number, larger than the first : " n2
echo "$n2"

seq "$n1" "$n2"
```

If you have to do it entirely in shell and can use a modern shell like `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` etc (but not `ash` or `dash` or similar strictly POSIX shell), you could replace the `seq` command with:

```
eval "printf '%s\n' {$n1..$n2}"
```

You need to use `eval` for the second version because bash/ksh/etc sequences expect actual integers like `{1..5}`, not variables like `{$n1..$n2}`.  `eval` expands the variables so that their actual values are used inside the `{...}` sequence.

if you want to do it with a loop and no fancy bash/ksh/etc features, you could replace the `seq` or `eval` lines with something like:

```
c="$n1"

while [ "$c" -le "$n2" ] ; do
    echo "$c"
    c=$((c+1))
done
```

This works in any POSIX-compatible shell, including `dash` and `ash`, as well as `bash` etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I can use bash. So i'm going to give it a try right now!

Comment: I try it just now and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help! I was way off on the second part!But now I know

Comment: BTW, if you want the output all on one line rather than each number on its own line, use `echo` rather than `printf '%s\n'`

Comment: printf '%s\n' works for what I need. However, this is a helpful hint for my next problem! Thanks!

Comment: you weren't completely off with the second part.  `bash` can do arithmetic, and you can combine that with a loop.  but `seq` exists, and `bash` also has built-in support for integer sequences - using either of them is easier and faster.   if you're trying to teach yourself, seeing how to do it with a loop is a useful.